# Chrome 10/11 and IE8/9 Issue with Iframe

Tags: iframe

I'm using iframe with its attribute of designMode set to on and its attribute of isEditable set to true for WYSIWYG text editing.  It works fine with Firefox 3.6x (I would expect fine as well with FF 4.0) and Safari 5.

Code snip:

```
<iframe id="myFRM" designMode="on" editable="true" src="blabla.html" />
```

However, it fails with Chrome 10/11 and IE8/9, that is, the iframe is rendered in read-only mode with these two browsers.

Does it mean these two browsers expect different coding for iframe or do they simply don't support iframe's use in the above scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you find the element using JavaScript and set `designMode` to `"on"`.

For example,

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("myFRM").contentDocument.designMode = "on";
</script>
```